# How to solve this improper integral $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ax}/(e^x+1) dx$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I need to solve the following integral.
$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\:\:\dfrac{e^{ax}}{e^x+1}dx$$

where $0<a<1$.

Comment: Your integral seems divergent.

Comment: Can you explain this why it is divergent?

Comment: Come on, people! It is convergent and is equal to $\mathrm{B}(a,1-a)=\dfrac{\pi}{\sin a\pi}$.

Comment: @metamorphy, please tell me how to proceed about it, what is $B(a,1-a)$ symbol? Would be really grateful for it.

Comment: It is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) (you need the first $\int_0^\infty$ formula).

Comment: But the beta function is defined from $0$ to $1$. Please elaborate more and don't mind if am asking very basic question in your point of view.

Comment: Did you find $\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{x-1}\,dt}{(1+t)^{x+y}}$ there? Please read the article before asking further questions - I wouldn't want to reproduce the whole of it here ;)

Comment: Can I solve this by Contour integration?

Comment: @John You could solve this integral using a rectangular contour which goes from -R to R on the real axis and which is of height $2\pi i$. Thus you have a pole at $x=\pi i$. If you edit your question so that it fits the rules of the site, I can maybe answer your question, because I had to solve this exact same integral today also using contour integration.

Comment: @Poujh That's honestly much easier than the approach I took. So thanks for helping me learn today.

Comment: @John I don't think this question should be closed due to your comment activity. If you edited to add more context in the post itself, I'd vote to reopen it

Comment: @Dylan, if possible, you could maybe edit your answer to add the method with this second contour. That could maybe help someone in the future. (If you have time to do it of course)

Comment: @Dylan please tell me what is f(z) in the solution given below?

Comment: It's the function in the integrand. $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^{1-a}(1+z)}$

Comment: @Poujh I've added your method to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Dylan What about the other poles in this second method? Of course $\exp(z)+1$ has zeros at $(2n+1)\pi i$.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $e^x \mapsto x$ gives

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{e^x+1}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1-a}(1+x)}dx $$

where $0 < 1-a < 1$

We can use complex integration here. Due to the pole at $z=-1$, we pick a branch cut on the positive real axis such that $0 \le \arg(z) < 2\pi$. The contour is a standard "keyhole contour" consisting of

- $C_1$: left semicircle centered at $0$ with radius $\epsilon$, going clockwise from $-\epsilon i$ to $\epsilon i$
- $C_2$: straight line from $\epsilon i$ to $R + \epsilon i$
- $C_3$: circle centered at $0$ with radius $R$, going counterclockwise from $R+i\epsilon$ to $R - \epsilon i$
- $C_4$: straight line from $R - \epsilon i$ to $-\epsilon i$

In the limits $\epsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$, the two straight line integrals converge to

$$ \int_{C_2} f(z)\ dz \to \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1-a}e^{i0(1-a)}(1+x)}dx = I $$

$$ \int_{C_4} f(z)\ dz \to -\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1-a}e^{i2\pi(1-a)}(1+x)}dx = -e^{i2\pi a}I $$

The remaining integrals should go to $0$

$$ \left\vert\int_{C_1} f(z)dz\right\vert \le \frac{\pi \epsilon}{|z|^{1-a}|1+z|} \le \frac{\pi \epsilon^a}{1-\epsilon} \to 0 $$

$$ \left\vert\int_{C_3} f(z) dz \right\vert \le \frac{2\pi R}{|z|^{1-a}|1+z|} \le \frac{2\pi R^a}{R-1} \to 0 $$

Therefore

$$ (1-e^{i2\pi a})I = 2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-1} f(z) = -2\pi i e^{i\pi a} $$

So finally

$$ I = \frac{2\pi ie^{i\pi a}}{e^{2\pi a}-1} = \frac{2\pi i}{e^{i\pi a}-e^{-i\pi a}} = \frac{\pi}{\sin(a\pi)} $$

---

**Edit:** Here's a simpler method, credit to @Poujh

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{e^x+1}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx $$

Take a rectangular contour:

- $C_1$: Straight line from $-R$ to $R$
- $C_2$: Straight line from $R$ to $R + i2\pi$
- $C_3$: Straight line from $R + i2\pi$ to $-R + i2\pi$
- $C_4$: Straight line from $-R + i2\pi$ to $-R$

---

In the limit of $R\to\infty$, we have

$$ \left\vert\int_{C_2} \frac{e^{az}}{e^z+1}\ dz\right\vert = \left\vert\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{a(R+iy)}}{e^{R+iy}+1} dy\right\vert \le 2\pi \left\vert\frac{e^{aR}}{e^R-1}\right\vert \to 0 $$

$$ \left\vert\int_{C_4} \frac{e^{az}}{e^z+1}\ dz\right\vert = \left\vert\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{a(-R+iy)}}{e^{-R+iy}+1} \right\vert \le 2\pi \left\vert \frac{e^{-aR}}{1-e^{-R}} \right\vert \to 0 $$

For the horizontal lines

$$ \int_{C_1} \frac{e^{az}}{e^z+1}\ dz \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{e^x+1}\ dx = I $$

$$ \int_{C_3} \frac{e^{az}}{e^z+1}\ dz \to -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}e^{i2\pi a}}{e^x+1} = -e^{i2\pi a} I $$

We end up with the same result

$$ (1-e^{i2\pi a})I = 2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i\pi} \frac{e^{az}}{e^z+1} $$

where the residue is computed using the limit

$$ \lim_{z\to i\pi} e^{az}\frac{z-i\pi}{e^z+1} = -e^{i\pi a} $$

Comment: What about the other poles in this second method? Of course $\exp(z)+1$ has zeros at $(2n+1)\pi i$.

Comment: @John The other poles are outside the contour

Comment: yes I got it and the residue is $- \exp(i \pi a)$, you can edit it.